# How do I update my google sheet in v4?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

I am new in google sheets v4 and I just want to know how can I update my google sheet in v4. I am using `Nodejs` and following is the code sample link which I am using [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sample script of the [link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update). In you case, combining Quickstart and the sample script may be useful for you. The sample script is as follows.

In this sample script, the text of `sample text` is imported to the cell `a1` of `Sheet1`.

### Sample script :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Google Sheets API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), valuesUpdate);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

function valuesUpdate(auth) {
  var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
  var request = {
    // The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
    spreadsheetId: 'my-spreadsheet-id',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // The A1 notation of the values to update.
    range: 'Sheet1!a1:a1',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // How the input data should be interpreted.
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    resource: {'values': [['sample text']]},

    auth: auth,
  };

  sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(request, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  });
}
```

### IMPORTANT :

- Please modify `my-spreadsheet-id` to yours in above script.
- This sample script supposes that the script of [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) works fine.
- After run the script of Quickstart, please remove `sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json` once, before run the above sample script. After remove the file, please run the above script. By this, the refresh token with the new scopes is retrieved and it is used for updating values.
- **If you want to use this script, please use googleapis v24 or less. Because the latest version doesn't work. Because the following error occurs, even if `valueInputOption` is set.**

  - `Error: 'valueInputOption' is required but not specified`
  - I believe that this error will be modified in the near future.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hey thanks @Tanaike ... Yes I am getting the same error  ```Error: 'valueInputOption' is required but not specified```

Comment: Hey thanks its working fine now I just downgrade my ```googleapis``` version to ```v24```. But for v24 we need to import googleapi something like this 
```var google = require('googleapis');```

Comment: @Himanshu Teotia I'm glad your problem was solved. I would like to expect the modification of such errors of googleapis.