# Youtube Data API V3 - Error fetching video with google.youtube.videos.list()

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am getting a cryptic error when trying to fetch a youtube video by it's Id:

`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

I previously had this working using (16.1.0) of `google-api-nodejs-client`, but after updating the package it no longer seems to work.

Here is the code I am using:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const youtube = google.youtube({ version: 'v3', auth: process.env.YOUTUBE_KEY });

youtube.videos.list({
  id: 'Txlk7PiHaGk',
  part: 'snippet, contentDetails'
}, (err, video) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`Error fetching Youtube Video: ${err}`);
  }
  // success..
});
```

For some reason my request errors every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, it has been reported that the recent googleapis for node.js has some errors. I had confirmed them for Gmail API, Drive API and Sheets API. Also at Youtube API, I found the same situation. I confirmed that for Youtube API, your script didn't work for v27.0.0, v26.0.0 and v25.0.0.

When I used v24.0.0, it worked fine.

So, can you downgrade to v24.0.0 and try it again? At that time, please modify from `const { google } = require('googleapis');` to `const google = require('googleapis');` I believe that these errors will be removed by the future update.

#### References :

- [How do I update my google sheet in v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898241/how-do-i-update-my-google-sheet-in-v4/48899290#48899290)
- [Create a gmail filter with Gmail API nodejs, Error: Filter doesn't have any criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186534/create-a-gmail-filter-with-gmail-api-nodejs-error-filter-doesnt-have-any-crit/49187226#49187226)
- [Insufficient Permission when trying to create a folder on Google Drive via API(v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204284/insufficient-permission-when-trying-to-create-a-folder-on-google-drive-via-apiv/49204457#49204457)

If this information is not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Awesome man, thank you. I realize I was quite a bit behind. Just happy to be more up to date.

Cheers

Comment: @Celestriel Thank you for your reply. From your question, I could know this version error for Youtube API. I would like to add your question to the reference of future answers. I think that this will help other users solve the same error.