# Google drive API - Cannot read property 'OAuth2' of undefined

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I am following [this quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs) to eventually be able to download certain files from my application.

As I followed through with the tutorial I got the error `Cannot read property 'OAuth2' of undefined` and it's coming from that line:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const google = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2Client = google.auth.OAuth2; << google.auth = undefined
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'credentials.json';
// the rest of the code is exactly as it is in the tutorial
```

I already installed googleapis @ 27 and here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "temp-google-drive-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have already reported that to google but in the interest of hopefully getting this done today has anyone here faced a similar issue?

Comment: Please try ``const {google} = require('googleapis');``. From v26.0.0, the usage was changed. https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/releases/tag/v26.0.0

Comment: That worked, thank you @Tanaike. Post it as an answer please so I can mark it as the solution

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I posted my answer with the additional information. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `const {google} = require('googleapis');`. From v26.0.0, it the usage was changed. https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/releases/tag/v26.0.0

Unfortunately, after the version of v25.0.0, some bugs for APIs and the options are reported. I believe that these bugs are removed in the future. So if for APIs and the options you use, some errors occur, please modify the version of googleapis, and try again.

#### References :

- [How do I update my google sheet in v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898241/how-do-i-update-my-google-sheet-in-v4/48899290#48899290)
- [Create a gmail filter with Gmail API nodejs, Error: Filter doesn't have any criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186534/create-a-gmail-filter-with-gmail-api-nodejs-error-filter-doesnt-have-any-crit/49187226#49187226)
- [Insufficient Permission when trying to create a folder on Google Drive via API(v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204284/insufficient-permission-when-trying-to-create-a-folder-on-google-drive-via-apiv/49204457#49204457)
- [Youtube Data API V3 - Error fetching video with google.youtube.videos.list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310299/youtube-data-api-v3-error-fetching-video-with-google-youtube-videos-list/49310978#49310978)