# googleapis "appProperties" field not being returned for files in node

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to get the `appProperties` field to be returned with my files on gdrive, but currently unable to get it working.

```
"googleapis": "^29.0.0"
```

Here's my scopes and fields:

```
scopes: [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"
  ]

fields = ["id", "name", "mimeType", "parents", "description", "modifiedTime", "appProperties"]
```

All of the other properties come back using `drive.files.list` without issue, but it won't return the `appProperties` field.

```
 getFilesByQuery: function( queryString , extraFields ){

    var fields = ["id", "name", "mimeType", "parents", "description", "modifiedTime", "appProperties"];
    if( extraFields && extraFields.length )
      fields = fields.concat( extraFields );

    return drive.files.list({
      'pageSize': 200,
      'fields': `nextPageToken, files(${ fields.join(', ') })`,
      'q': queryString
    });
  }
```

When I query directly through files/get on dev.google API, this is what I get back for that file:

```
{
 "name": "US",
 "appProperties": {
  "order": "1"
 }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we ask you about the script calling Drive API using ``fields`` of your question?

Comment: @Tanaike updated for clarity!

Comment: Thank you for the response. What version of googleapis are you using? Because  googleapis with v25.0.0 - v30.0.0 has some bugs, I worry it for your situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258645/how-to-run-a-google-app-script-using-google-api-service-library-node-js/50262736

Comment: V: "^29.0.0", any recommendations for testing this? Should I downgrade to 24.0?

Comment: I'm sorry. In my current environment, I cannot try it. But I think it's worth a try.

Comment: In my environment, I could confirm that ``appProperties`` can be retrieved using googleapis with v29.0.0. I'm really sorry for late response.

Comment: @Tanaike. Thanks for checking! Are you using `files.list`, or `file.get`?

Comment: I confirmed for both. And I thought about the possibility of the reason for your situation. I posted it. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my environment, I confirmed that `appProperties` can be retrieved using `files.list` and `files.get` of googleapis with v29.0.0. And I thought about the possibility of the reason for your situation. So can you confirm the following point?

When I read the document of [Custom File Properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties), it says as follows.

> Properties are accessed using the properties (visible to all apps) and appProperties (restricted to single apps) fields on files

I investigated about this. As a sample, it supposes that `{"key1": "value1"}` was written to `appProperties` and `properties` by **client_id_A**.

- For `appProperties`, when the `appProperties` is read, only the client ID which is the same with the client ID used when `appProperties` was written can read it.

  - Namely, when the access token retrieved from **client_id_B** is used, it cannot read `appProperties` written by **client_id_A**.
- For `properties`, when the `properties` is read, it can be read by various client IDs.

  - Namely, even if the access token retrieved from **client_id_B** is used, it can read `properties` written by **client_id_A**.

From these results, `appProperties` and `properties` can be used as "Private" and "Public", respectively.

Using this, can you confirm your situation again? If you will write `appProperties` using node.js, you can use the following script. By this, you can confirm that you can write and read `appProperties` using the same client ID.

```
drive.files.update({
  fileId: "### file ID ###",
  resource: {"appProperties": {"key": "value"}},
  fields: 'id,appProperties',
});
```

If this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: That was definitely the problem. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out! You're awesome!

Comment: @Mk-Etlinger Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. Also I could study from your question. Thank you, too.