# Error: No access, refresh token or API key is set

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make an app in Node to access my google calendar, so I followed the steps at https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs but I'm getting `Error: Error: No access, refresh token or API key is set.`.

Yes I have created the credentials.

Yes I have downloaded the json, renamed to client_secret.json and added to the application folder.

Here is the code:

```js
    const fs = require('fs'); 
    const readline = require('readline'); 
    const {google} = require('googleapis'); 
    const OAuth2Client = google.auth.OAuth2; 
    const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']; 
    const TOKEN_PATH = './client_secret.json';
        
    try {   
        const content = fs.readFileSync('client_secret.json');   
        authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents); 
    } catch (err) {   
        return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err); 
    }
        
    function authorize(credentials, callback) {   
        const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;   
        let token = {};   
        const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
        
          // Check if we have previously stored a token.   
        try {
            token = fs.readFileSync(TOKEN_PATH);   
        } catch (err) {
            return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);   
        }   
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));   
        callback(oAuth2Client); 
    }
        
    function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {   
        const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline',
            scope: SCOPES,   
        });   
        console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);   
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout,   
        });   
        rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
            rl.close();
            oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
                // Store the token to disk for later program executions
                try {
                    fs.writeFileSync(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
                    console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            callback(oAuth2Client);
            });   
        }); 
    }
        
    function listEvents(auth) {   
        const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});   
        calendar.events.list({
            calendarId: 'primary',
            timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
            maxResults: 10,
            singleEvents: true,
            orderBy: 'startTime',   }, (err, {data}) => {
                if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                const events = data.items;
                if (events.length) {
                    console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
                    events.map((event, i) => {
                    const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
                    console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
                });
            } else {
              console.log('No upcoming events found.');
            }   
    }); 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "the application folder" is the same with ``const TOKEN_PATH = './client_secret.json';``?

Comment: Yes, I can see the contents loaded from the file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted the confirmation points. Please check it.

Comment: @BrunoAraújo was this issue ever resovled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you confirm as following points again?

- The files of `const TOKEN_PATH = './client_secret.json';` and `const content = fs.readFileSync('client_secret.json');` are the same.

  - Please modify from `const TOKEN_PATH = './client_secret.json';` to `const TOKEN_PATH = './credentials.json';`, and run again.
  - **By this, `client_secret.json` that you downloaded has already might be overwritten. So please also confirm this.**
- When an error occurs even if above modification was done, please confirm the version of googleapis. Because it has been reported that googleapis with v25.0.0 - v30.0.0. has some bugs for some APIs.

  - If you think a bug for the error, please modify the version of googleapis to v24.0.0. The error may be removed.

#### References :

- [How do I update my google sheet in v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898241/how-do-i-update-my-google-sheet-in-v4/48899290#48899290)
- [Create a gmail filter with Gmail API nodejs, Error: Filter doesn't have any criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186534/create-a-gmail-filter-with-gmail-api-nodejs-error-filter-doesnt-have-any-crit/49187226#49187226)
- [Insufficient Permission when trying to create a folder on Google Drive via API(v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204284/insufficient-permission-when-trying-to-create-a-folder-on-google-drive-via-apiv/49204457#49204457)
- [Youtube Data API V3 - Error fetching video with google.youtube.videos.list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310299/youtube-data-api-v3-error-fetching-video-with-google-youtube-videos-list/49310978#49310978)
- [Google drive API - Cannot read property 'OAuth2' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848105/google-drive-api-cannot-read-property-oauth2-of-undefined/49848309)
- [How to run a Google App Script using Google API Service Library (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258645/how-to-run-a-google-app-script-using-google-api-service-library-node-js/50262736)

If these points were not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks. The files on both token and readFile were the same,  changing the TOKEN_PATH to ./credentials.json was a game changer.